# URL requests with Python

Tags: python, url, python-requests

I just finished a short program to check if the URL is valid or not and the accessibility. But, anyhow from the try/except block does not work properly
and I couldn't figure out why. Even if I enter proper URL it does not print out the result I need.

I'll list the code below just check the try/except block:

```
import os
import requests
import string


def url_check(url):
  try:
    resp = requests.get(url)
    if resp.requests.status_code == 200:
      print(f">>> {url} is up!")
    else:
      print(f">>> {url} is down!") # Normal URL but down
  except:
        print(f">>> {url} is down!") # invalid URL
  return


def restart():
  print("\nDo you want to start over? y/n", end=' ')
  choice = input()

  if choice.lower() == 'y':
    main()
  elif choice.lower() == 'n':
    print("Okay. Bye!")
    exit()
  else:
    print("That's not a valid answer")
    restart()


def main():
  os.system('clear')
  print("Welcome to IsItDown.py!")
  print("Please write a URL or URLs you wnat to check. (separated by a comma)")

  while True:
    urls = input().split(',')

    for url in urls:
      url = url.strip(string.punctuation).strip().lower()
      if "." not in url:
        print(f"{url} is not a valid URL")
        break 
      else:
        if "http" not in url:
          url = "http://" + url
          url_check(url)
    restart()

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

Comment: Never completely hide an exception with a black box and generic `try`/`except`. At least print out the error message.

Comment: @KlausD.Do you mean by 'except Exception as e:' ?

Comment: The more important part would be an additional `print(e)` or similar.

Answer (score 0):

Your if statement should look like this.

```
if resp.status_code == 200:
```

since resp its already an requests instance

Answer (score 0):

If you take out the requests in for your if statement, it works fine!

```
def url_check(url):
    try:
        resp = requests.get(url)
        if resp.status_code == 200:
```